# How do I use an IOC container with typescript generics in node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics, inversion-of-control

I am attempting to use [container-ioc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/container-ioc), but am happy to use any package supplying IoC. I cannot find any examples that use typescript generics. Basically, I want:

```
interface A<T> {
    foo();
}

class A<T> {
    foo() {
    }
}

interface B<T> {
    bar: A<T>;
}

class B<T> {
    bar: A<T>;
    constructor(param: A<T>) {
       this.bar = param;
    }
}
```

where I can set up an IoC container to inject A into B. I am using typescript in a node app. I have syntax that seems to parse at least, but cannot craft the container resolve() as I don't know how to pass the generic parameter. Not to mention, I'm not sure whether this is actually supported.

Answer (score -1):

So, I have a workaround that works for my situation. Firstly, I set a symbol for the generic type with `const MyFoo = Symbol("Foo<My>")`. Then, I use a factory constructor when registering the type:

```
container.register([    
    { token: MyBar, useFactory: () => new Bar<My>() },
      token: MyFoo, useFactory: () => new Foo<My>( container.resolve(MyBar) )}]);
```

Finally, I do not @inject the parameter on the constructor. This method means that I need to know what generic types I will be using beforehand. In my case, I do: my generic types implement an entity repository and related classes, and my entities are the generic parameters. I'd prefer to not have yet another place to maintain when setting up new entities, so I am leaving this answer unaccepted in case someone has a better solution.